# Booting Windows 8 using Grub Command

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I am Using Both Ubuntu and Windows 8 on my laptop.
I want to hide the Windows Menu title from the grub-menu and boot it through the grub command.
 After i get into Grub after pressing C and typing 
chainloader (hd0,gpt5) +1,the promt shows no such file found.
My windows is in Gpt5,while ubuntu is in gpt6.

Some1 tell me how to hide the Windows menu and use grub command to boot It

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I also got a problem like this and solved it using the following commands:

This is where `5` has Windows 8:

```
grub>rootnoverify(hd0,5)
grub>makeactive
grub>chainloader +1
grub>boot
```

Comment: I would suggest to keep communications on this site, this information might help other people with the same problem. Also be aware of the risks of leaving email addresses out in the open on the Internet.